# Simulating "falling" objects on UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I am just testing some animation of "falling" views. I want to simulate leafs that fall from the sky. I have made this really simple code which is unfinished, but was used to check if I was  doing it right.

However, should the "falling" views have `auto layout` constraints attached to them? Is it bad to just add views to the screen like this when the rest of the view is done with auto layout? *I am using `Swift 2` and `iOS 9`.*

```
let rectangleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
rectangleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
backgroundView.addSubview(rectangleView)

UIView.animateWithDuration(10, delay: 0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn], animations: {
    rectangleView.center = CGPoint(x: rectangleView.center.x, y: 300)
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: if it is just falling animation, (i think it is just a view moving from top to bottom), I suggest you to change the rectangleView top and bottom constraints, instead of center, and do layout if needed after the animation.

Comment: yeah, the falling view have the layout constraints attacthced !!!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean, I did not understand properly?

Comment: I meant to say, if the falling view has some constriants set before, and you want to animate the fallingView, then instead of changing the falling view center, you can change the falling view top/bottom constraint . In this way, you dont need to worry about the autolayout!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your views are moving freely on the screen, then I don't see any reason to use auto layout constraints.

There is no issue adding a subview to a UI that uses auto layout and animating it yourself, as you are doing.  Not everything on the screen has to be managed by auto layout.